# Android sqlExcetion opening db : Permission denied JDBC

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sdk, android-sqlite

I try to create and use SQLite database in Android(API 25).
I provide permission in manifest. I think maybe there is problem with database Path. But I can`t solve this problem...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissio8n.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

There is database opening code

```
String db = "jdbc:sqlite:" + Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyDatabase.db";
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

But there is some errors regarding permissions

```
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: opening db: '/data/MyDatabase.db': Permission denied
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:203)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:237)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at com.example.user.app.DB.openDbConnection(DB.java:33)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at com.example.user.app.Helpers.isTableIsEmpty(Helpers.java:24)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at com.example.user.app.activity.BachelorITFCourses1.onCreate(BachelorITFCourses1.java:42)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
06-05 21:05:35.962 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-05 21:05:35.963 3698-3698/com.example.user.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

P.S. I have special class DB for dtabase actions.

Answer (score 0):

The 8 in permission...READ is wrong right?
And are you requesting the permissions? I think writing and reading external storage is critical and has to be requested:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

So you think I need to request the permissions I need? Something like this?

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```